# Fedora 33 dnf gpgcheck values ignored

Tags: dnf

Need to install the latest version rpm of an app I've installed and upgraded many times.
(I download it with its gpg signature files signed by the dev, and use dnf to localinstall.)

After recent Fedora 33 updates, this is not working anymore.
Get error:

> Package MyUpgradedApp.rpm is not signed
> Error: GPG check FAILED

> sudo dnf -v --nogpgcheck install

doesn't work, and neither does setting gpgcheck=0 in global policy.

What's the best workaround?

Update: I tried also to import the app dev's pgp key that they use to sign the .asc detached signature file for the rpm into rpmkeys, which didn't help, because it's only a detached pgp signature file. The rpm itself isn't signed the way rpm or dnf require.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you everyone, particularly the dnf devs that may have seen my question for your overwhelming support and help!

Another dnf update just came down and still has the same problem.

I had to use rpm to remove and reinstall the package, which broke my links, but finally was able to upgrade.

Thank you again to dnf devs for your tremendous work.